# check whether any one of the object is null and proceed with other

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, c#-6.0

I have a  list like as this below in a class

```
public class DesignHubProject{
   public List<ProjectObject<HydronicSystem>> HydronicSystems { get; set; }
}
```

here is the object that `ProjectObject<HydronicSystem>` is holding

```
public class ProjectObject<T>
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public T OriginalObject { get; set; }
    public T ModifiedObject { get; set; }
}
```

Now i need to find if modified object is null i need to proceed with the original object or if it is not null use modified object it self.

for this i am looping through the object like as below

```
    foreach(var item in designHubProject.HydronicSystems)
    {
           // here i need to check for modified object is null proceed with original object and 
            // if original object is null proceed with modified object           
    }
```

how can i check the object proceed with that, Could any one please suggest any idea on this that would be very grateful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What did that code do? How is that different from what you want? And most importantly, what _specifically_ is it that you are having trouble figuring out? Please read [ask] to see information about how to present a good question, in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: Your wording is confusing "*i need to find if modified object is null i need to proceed with the original object and vice-versa.*", can you clarify.. If the modified is not null, why not just use the modified , why are you checking if original is null after the fact?

Comment: here is the fact , if modified object is null i can use original object.. if modified object is not null i can use modified itself

Comment: You can check by doing `if(item.OriginalObject == null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [Extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) (usefull for code reuse):

```
public static class ProjectObjectExtension
{
    public static T GetObject<T>(this ProjectObject<T> projectObject)
        => projectObject.ModifiedObject ?? projectObject.OriginalObject;

    // or like @MichaelRandall suggests in his answer
    public static T GetObjectMichaelRandallWay<T>(this ProjectObject<T> projectObject)
        => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(projectObject.ModifiedObject, default) ?
            projectObject.OriginalObject :
            projectObject.ModifiedObject;
}
```

Then just call this method:

```
foreach(var item in designHubProject.HydronicSystems)
{
    var obj = item.GetObject();
    // rest of your code...
}
```

Or just call this code within your loop:

```
foreach(var item in designHubProject.HydronicSystems)
{
    var obj = item.ModifiedObject ?? item.OriginalObject;
    // rest of your code...
}
```

You may also use LINQ `.Select()` method:

```
foreach(var obj in designHubProject.HydronicSystems.Select(p => p.ModifiedObject ?? p.OriginalObject))
{
    // rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: hah GetObjectMichaelRandallWay :) youll get a point for that. Just for completeness `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(obj, default)` avoids boxing respects `IEquatable<T>` as well as `object.Equals`, and handles *nullable*